# Dump output using execute() in neovim

Tags: neovim, original-vim

Currently, I am using `nnoremap <leader>d :vnew +pu=execute('')<left><left>` to dump output in both vim and neovim.
I tried it with `verbose imap <tab>` but it didn't work

`nnoremap <leader>d :vnew +pu=execute('verbose imap <tab>')<left><left>`

Comment: I think the problem is that a command passed with `+cmd` to e.g. `:vnew` needs to have no spaces... Using `:vnew +pu=execute('verbose\ imap\ <tab>')` seems to work for me. Can you check that's the case for you too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is failing because when you use the [`+cmd`](https://vimhelp.org/editing.txt.html#%5B%2Bcmd%5D) argument to `:vnew`, you need to escape spaces with backslashes. As `:help +cmd` points out:

> To include a white space in the `{pat}` or `{command}`, precede it with a backslash.

So, in your case, using the following would work:

```
:vnew +pu=execute('verbose\ imap\ <tab>')
```

Perhaps a better approach is to define a new [user-command](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#user-commands) that would encapsulate the implementation. In that case, you can also modify the opened buffer to become a [scratch-buffer](https://vimhelp.org/windows.txt.html#scratch-buffer), since you probably don't want to save its contents when quitting.

For example:

```
function! Dump(cmd)
  vnew
  setlocal buftype=nowrite bufhidden=delete noswapfile
  let result = trim(execute(a:cmd))
  put! =result
  1
endfunction
command! -nargs=* -complete=command Dump call Dump(<q-args>)
```

Which you can then use with:

```
:Dump verbose imap <tab>
```

Defining a user-command is also useful in that you can set up tab completion. In this case, to complete Vim commands, which is what you want to pass `execute()`.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is exactly what I need.